# Trying to specific values from a mysql column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql (text)column that contains all comments with hash tags and I'm looking for a way to select only the hash tags

```
Id | Column
1  | I'm #cool and #calm
2  | l like #manchester
3  | #mysql troubles not #cool
```

Comment: In the long run... it would be easier to separate those kinds of things out before inserting.  You would have a `tag` table and then a `tag_comment` joining table.  Is there a limit on the number of tags a comment may contain?  What do you ultimately want to do with the result?  You could use regex to clean out anything that doesn't start with `#` but I'm assuming you'd want to further split that result into rows or columns...?  There's a lot of code and stored procedures out there for this kind of thing if you google a little.

Comment: I do not think you can really do it query level, since queries are not meant to do these kind of JOB. However you can write some stored procedure to get the job done or use the application level to handle this. And the best way is to normalize the data if you want to get the job done with query.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do what you want by using `substring_index()` to do the parsing.  Assuming that the character after the hash tag is a space, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       substring_index(substring_index(comment, '#', n.n + 1), ' ', 1)
from table t join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
     on n.n <= length(t.comment) - length(replace(t.comment, '#', '')) ;
```

The fancy `on` clause is counting the number of `#` in the comment, which is counting the number of tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regular Expressions**

Try this Regular Expression:

```
/(#[A-Za-z])\w+
```

Demo:
[http://regexr.com/3a2q7][1]